# Having some trouble with collision using Arrays and Childs

Tags: actionscript-3

So, i was working on a game and i got some trouble at the part where i was coding the collision detection between my character and an item. When both collide, the item should dissapear, but it crashes the game. I'm coding using Flashdevelop and Starling. Here's my code:

```
private function collision(object1:DisplayObject, object2:Sprite):Boolean
        {
            var area1:Rectangle = object1.getBounds(stage);
            var area2:Rectangle = object2.getBounds(stage);

            if (area1.intersects(area2)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

private function collisionPlayerItem(object:Player):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
                if (collision(object.areaBody(), itemArray[i])) {
                    if(stage.contains(itemArray[i])){
                        map.removeChild(itemArray[i]);

                        life -= 1;


                }
            }
        }
```

itemArray is where all the items are stocked in.
areaBody is the hitbox of my character.

The moment my character touch an item, the game crashes.
In flashdevelop there is no hitTestObject also.
Someone knows whats happening?

Comment: I think the problem is your players are added on stage and you are removing them from map or viceversa

Comment: You might need to remove the item from your itemArray on collision as well ? Since the item is removed from the stage on collision it is likely to produce an error when you check the collision against it on the next iteration. Are there any exception / error messages that you are getting ?